# Heroku: possible to turn custom error pages off?

Tags: heroku

I've just migrated a Node.js site (built on Express) to Heroku, and I'm seeing that in the case of application errors, Heroku shows its custom error page instead of whatever my app is returning.

I'd like it to not do that, since Express already provides [a mechanism](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#error-handling) to do that, and my app does that. Is it possible to tell Heroku to use whatever my app is returning?

One example why I'd prefer this is because my app's error page can properly show the logged-in or logged-out state, which a static page, e.g. on S3, couldn't do. Another example is that my app actually shows different pages based on the precise 5xx status code, whereas Heroku treats all 5xx codes the same.

***Edit:** Thought of another particularly noteworthy example: our app creates unique IDs for every error instance, and shows that ID to the user on the error page, so that if/when they contact us, we can look up that exact error instance in our logs. Wouldn't be able to do that with a static page.*

I realize Heroku only detects errors via the status code, so I could just send 200 back in the case of errors. But that seems wrong -- e.g. you don't send 200 back in the case of 404s. (And come to think of it, how would a REST API on Heroku return JSON for 5xx then? Hopefully Heroku's custom error pages only override HTML responses?)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked the log to make sure your app isn't actually crashing or throwing some other kind of error?  If you're seeing a 503 every time, it may mean something else.  See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes.

Comment: I'm pretty sure my app isn't crashing or failing to catch an exception (which would crash the app in Node.js's case), but good question -- let me confirm that's the case.

Comment: Hace you looked at the custom error codes config var? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom_error_pages

Comment: @Schneems, are you referring to `ERROR_PAGE_URL`? That's a custom error page -- it points to a static HTML page. My question was overriding that altogether and letting my app return dynamic HTML pages.

Comment: @AseemKishore yes I am, Neil's answer below is correct, just wanted to let you and anyone else with a similar question be aware of the option.

Comment: You can your own custom error pages in dashboard > settings > Error Pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly answer the question - no, you cannot turn off the Heroku error pages…

The errors that Heroku handle are the ones that your application isn't, so if your application is catching errors and returning a page, then Heroku won't intervene.

I have many apps, admittedly not Node, that do this.

Comment: Thanks Neil. I'll look into why my app might be returning Heroku's error page then.

Comment: You were right, Neil -- regular errors do return my app's error page just fine. Heroku's error pages show up if my app fails to respond in 30 secs. Thanks again.